# Can someone make this Angular 16 checkbox input code more efficient and cleaner?

Tags: checkbox, html-input, angular16

I have a simple boolean in my angular 16 ts component `uploadEnabled`. What I want is the checkbox to be checked if `uploadEnabled` is true and vice versa. When I click on the checkbox I want `uploadEnabled` to toggle accordingly with the state of the checkbox. I have a label element showing the current state of `uploadEnabled`.

The following code does what I want but it is clearly clumsy as I am using two input elements and `*ngIf` to either have the `checked` attribute present or absent. (I have removed `class` attributes for readability.)

```
      <form >
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="uploadEnabled = !uploadEnabled" *ngIf="!uploadEnabled" />
        <input type="checkbox" (click)="uploadEnabled = !uploadEnabled" *ngIf="uploadEnabled" checked />
        <label >Allow PHG to perform FHIR/PCD01 uploads:
          {{uploadEnabled}}</label>
      </form>
```

The variant below does half the job. The checkbox will be checked or unchecked when first viewed depending upon the boolean, but clicking on the checkbox sets the checkbox to checked if not checked  otherwise it just remains checked. The boolean value, however, toggles as desired:

```
        <input type="checkbox"
          (click)="uploadEnabled = !uploadEnabled" [checked] = "uploadEnabled" />
        <label >Allow PHG to perform FHIR/PCD01 uploads:
          {{uploadEnabled}}</label>
```

I have tried other variants with '[(ngModel)]' and '(change)' but either I have gotten compile errors (I am using Angular 16 with strict mode) or I could not get consistency between the check box state and the variable. In the end all I am trying to do it eliminate the `checked` attribute when `uploadEnabled` is false and to have it present when `uploadEnabled` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is an Angular directive [(ngModel)] that does exactly this:

```
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="advanced.retrieveStoredMeasurements" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  <label> Automatically retrieve stored measurements</label>
</span>
```

advanced.retrieveStoredMeasurements is the boolean. I have taken out the class attributes for readability.